# jQuery circular reference

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I made a jQuery plugin/widget as an OOP object and in that object I am saving the HTML/jQuery element (`$elem`) as a property. I am also storing that object's reference (created using `new`) in the `data` attribute of the HTML element. Would this cause circular reference/memory leakage?

The code in CoffeeScript would roughly be:

```
class wid
  constructor
    @$elem = $('<div>hello</div>')
    @$elem.appendTo('body')
    @$elem.data('obj',@)  // adding the instance to the element's data attribute
  updateText: (p)->
     @$ele.text(p)

widget = new wid()
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: As a property of _what_?

Comment: When said element is deleted, the data in the data attribute will be cleared, thus allowing the memory to be cleared. It is very common to include a reference to the object instance in the elements data with jQuery Plugins.

Comment: Doesn't `data()` need two parameters to set data, and only one if retrieving the data?

Comment: typo...updated with the code..

Comment: @KevinB my concern was since the $elem is pointing to the element and the element in turn in pointing to the object...and the object contains the link to th element..does it not go into infinite pointing each other

Answer (score -3):

On a real browser, no.  Internet Explorer, Microsoft's browser-shaped object, has separate garbage collectors for the DOM and for Javascript, so it's easy to create circular references.  Since IE is tightly integrated with the operating system, merely shutting down the browser does not free this memory: the OS has to be rebooted.

However, this is a good thing: as IE becomes slower and slower, weighed down with unfreed object references, the user learns a vital lesson about Microsoft quality.

Comment: Well with that thought process I could just browser-sniff for IE and intentionally run code that will slow the browser down.  I think what you'll find is that the user blames your site for slowness, not necessarily their specific browser.

Comment: @nzifnab Exactly. Blatant partiality aside, it's much worth noting that IE since version 8 has had a mark-and-sweep GC, which doesn't share a reference counter's general susceptibility to circular reference leaks. (It's also worth noting, for those of us who apparently haven't looked out a window since 1996, that killing an `iexplore.exe` process will free whatever memory it has allocated, just as with any other process on an NT box.)

Comment: @nzifnab -- that's the wonderful thing about this strategy!  It doesn't affect the site doing the work any more than any other site -- or the browser more than any other app.  All that happens is they understand Microsoft's commitment to the user experience in a comparatively painless way.

Comment: @AaronMiller -- the problem isn't the GC strategy, it's that there are two separate memory pools, and no GC coordination between them.  As for the memory issue, I haven't tested it myself, I'm just parroted Microsoft's corporate guidance on the issue, which yes might not be completely reliable.

Comment: @Malvolio I'd like to see a primary source for, oh, any of what you're saying.